# Passing a List inside ViewModel from View to Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, controller

I'm creating an application that books Guests in hotelrooms. I'm trying to edit Guests in a List that is contained within a ReservationViewModel. On the GET I successfully pass the ViewModel with two empty Guest items to the View, and create editors in the View. Whenever I send back the ReservationVM and try to read them the List shows up empty. I've changed my foreach loop to a for loop as suggested but that doesn't seem to work. The list seems to be empty, I try to print a message whenever it tries to read from the List but nothing outputs.

Here is my GET:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit2(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Reservation reservation = resRepo.GetReservationByID(id);
        ReservationVM reservationVM = new ReservationVM(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < reservation.amount_people; i++)
        {
            reservationVM.guests.Add(new Guest());
        }

        foreach (Guest guest in reservationVM.guests)
        {
            guest.name = " ";
            guest.zipcode = " ";
            guest.housenumber = 0;
            guest.suffix = "";
            guest.email = " ";
            guestRepo.AddGuest(guest);
        }
        guestRepo.Save();

        reservationVM.date = (DateTime)reservation.date;
        reservationVM.amount_people = (int)reservation.amount_people;
        reservationVM.ID = reservation.ID;
        reservationVM.room_ID = (int)reservation.room_ID;

        if (reservation == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(reservationVM);
    }
```

Here is my POST:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit2(ReservationVM reservationVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Get reservation
            Reservation reservation = resRepo.GetReservationByID(reservationVM.ID);
            //Update values in model 
            reservation.date = reservationVM.date;
            reservation.amount_people = reservationVM.amount_people;
            reservation.ID = reservationVM.ID;
            reservation.room_ID = reservationVM.room_ID;
            Debug.WriteLine(reservation.ID);
            //Update to DB and save changes
            resRepo.UpdateReservation(reservation);
            resRepo.Save();
            
            foreach(Guest guest in reservationVM.guests)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("hello");
                guestRepo.UpdateGuest(guest);
                reservation.Guests.Add(guest);
            }
            guestRepo.Save();

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(reservationVM);
    }
```

Here is my view:
[image]

Editing:    Passing a List inside ViewModel from View to Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. First off, please don't give us screenshots of your code and please do make the effort to format it properly inside a code block. I also encourage you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and carefully reconsider your edits.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK to me, guess your action might need to have prefix

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit2([Bind(Include = "guests")]DataReservationVM reservationVM)
{
.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't seem to work. It doesn't seem to be posting at all. I created a partial view for the guests too. And it does load in the empty Guests but it doesn't post. The ReservationVM object that I get is completely empty. It's a completely fresh ReservationVM object it seems. Any way I can reach you more directly?

Comment: check if your post action get hit or nor

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Thanks for the help. My problem were the bindings. Added `[Bind(Include ="date, amount_people,ID,room_ID,guests")]` Also creating a partial view for the Guest object seemed to help the binding.

Comment: Glad to hear that, happy coding